# How To: Pattern Recognition

Tags: pattern-recognition

I'm interested in learning more about pattern recognition.  I know that's somewhat of a broad field, so I'll list some specific types of problems I would like to learn to deal with:

- Finding patterns in a seemingly random set of bytes.
- Recognizing known shapes (such as circles and squares) in images.
- Noticing movement patterns given a stream of positions (Vector3)

This is a new area of experimentation for me personally, and to be honest, I simply don't know where to start :-) I'm obviously not looking for the answers to be provided to me on a silver platter, but some search terms and/or online resources where I can start to acquaint myself with the concepts of the above problem domains would be awesome.

Thanks!

*ps: For extra credit, if said resources provide code examples/discussion in C# would be grand :-) but doesn't need to be*

Comment: I am glad that this interesting question did not get flagged as Too Broad or  "Asking for tutorials is off-topic" as it clearly is, because I benefit from the links in the answers.

Comment: @Roland indeed ... I asked this in the early days of StackOverflow, when they wanted to have canonical questions and answers that would be improved over time and indexed accordingly. Wish things would go back to that, I've learned a great deal from the answers here as well :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Hidden Markov Models are a great place to look, as well as [Artificial Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network).

Edit: You could take a look at [NeuronDotNet](http://neurondotnet.freehostia.com/index.html), it's open source and you could poke around the code.

Edit 2: You can also take a look at [ITK](http://www.itk.org/), it's also open source and implements a lot of these types of algorithms.

Edit 3: Here's a pretty good [intro to neural nets](http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html).  It covers a lot of the basics and includes source code (albeit in C++).  He implemented an unsupervised learning algorithm, I think you may be looking for a supervised [backpropagation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) to train your network.

Edit 4: Another [good intro](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-neural/), avoids really heavy math, but provides references to a lot of that detail at the bottom, if you want to dig into it.  Includes pseudo-code, good diagrams, and a lengthy description of backpropagation.

Answer (score 4):

OpenCV has some functions for pattern recognition in images.

You might want to look at this :http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/pattern_recognition.html. (broken link: closest thing in the new doc is http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/ml__machine_learning.html, although it is no longer what I'd call helpful documentation for a beginner - see other answers)

However, I also recommend starting with Matlab because openCV is not intuitive to use.

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of like saying "I'd like to learn more about electronics.. anyone tell me where to start?" Pattern Recognition is a whole field - there are hundreds, if not thousands of books out there, and any university has at least several (probably 10 or more) courses at the grad level on this. There are numerous journals dedicated to this as well, that have been publishing for decades ... conferences ..

You might start with the wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of an old question, but it's relevant so I figured I'd post it here :-) Stanford began offering an online Machine Learning class here - http://www.ml-class.org

Answer (score 2):

Lot of useful links on [this page](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~godfried/teaching/pr-web.html#introduction) on computer vision related pattern recognition. Some of the links seem to be broken now but you may find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on this, but reading about [Hidden Markov Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) is a good way to start.

Answer (score 1):

Beware false patterns!  For any decently large data set you will find subsets that appear to have pattern, even if it is a data set of coin flips.  No good process for pattern recognition should be without statistical techniques to assess confidence that the detected patterns are real.  When possible, run your algorithms on random data to see what patterns they detect.  These experiments will give you a baseline for the strength of a pattern that can be found in random (a.k.a "null") data.  This kind of technique can help you assess the "false discovery rate" for your findings.

Answer (score 0):

learning pattern-recoginition is easier in matlab..

there are several examples and there are functions to use.

it is good for the understanding concepts and experiments...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with some MATLAB toolbox. MATLAB is an especially convenient place to start playing around with stuff like this due to its interactive console. A nice toolbox I personally used and really liked is PRTools ([http://prtools.org](http://www.prtools.org)); they have an implementation of pretty much every pattern recognition tool and also some other machine learning tools (Neural Networks, etc.). But the nice thing about MATLAB is that there are many other toolboxes as well you can try out (there is even a [proprietary toolbox](http://www.mathworks.nl/machine-learning/) from Mathworks)

Whenever you feel comfortable enough with the different tools (and found out which classifier is perfomring best for you problem), you can start thinking about implementing the machine learning in a different application.